# Compiling Dash app to react web component

Tags: reactjs, plotly-dash

we are looking to embed a dash application on a website with php backend. For those not familiar with dash, it is a productive Python framework for building web applications written on top of Flask, Plotly.js, and React.js.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-web-component

One of the ways, we’re thinking this could work is by compiling the dash app as react web component. I was wondering if it is technically feasible to do so.

We have a login API that can be used for authentication and SSO.